# Put a changing variable within a data bracket search using getJSON

Tags: javascript, object

This code correctly gets the RSI of the Nasdaq:

```
var rsi='https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=rsi&symbol=qqq&interval=5min&time_period=50&series_type=open&apikey=RXPKZJXB6JLMZNP6'
$.getJSON(rsi,function(data) {
   alert(data["Technical Analysis: RSI"]["2019-07-19 16:00"]["RSI"])
});
```

Now I need to switch ["2019-07-19 16:00"] for the current date time because the time is always changing. Something like this:

```
 alert(data["Technical Analysis: RSI"].today["RSI"])
 alert(data["Technical Analysis: RSI"][today]["RSI"])
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

By the way, this question is not how to get datetime. I am just not sure how to put a "changing variable" within a bracket in the middle of a data search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `today` is the date-time string in the format you've described, it's the same way as your second approach:

```
alert(data["Technical Analysis: RSI"][today]["RSI"]);
```

It's fine to chain bracket notation accessors like that.

Comment: Interesting. I will have to try my second solution again. Yes I had var today= to todays date (when time was not needed for a more simple example)

Comment: Can you `console.log(today)` and make sure it's *exactly* what you want? Even a leading or trailing space will mean it doesn't work, and it's *extremely* hard to spot those - particularly a trailing space.

Comment: Yes it worked thanks. By the way, is it possibly to get the latest index by doing a [0] instead of a timestamp? If so, that way would be way more simple.